# Variable URL setup method with Test Complete 11.11.1064.7

Tags: variables, automated-tests, testcomplete

I am using test complete to create a test suite for a web based application. The URL for the login and home page needs to be variable as we have development and release versions of the application so this need's to be addressed for our tests. (The url in the example i have changed from the live one for privacy reasons)

http://100.00.0.00/dev/testweb/#/routehome that is written to the test steps. Which is no good because when we run the tests on another URL. So I've set up a variable with project scope that stores the base url , then each keyword test has a variable for the page URL. Each keyword test then needs a "Run Code Snippet" to concatenate the two to get the full URL of the page under test.
so i have built

```
Project.Variables.BaseURL = http://100.00.0.00/dev/testweb/
KeywordTests.LoginToTEST.Variables.PageURL = #routehome
KeywordTests.LoginToTEST.Variables.TestURL = Project.Variables.BaseURL + KeywordTests.LoginToTEST.Variables.PageURL
```

Every keyword test needs to run :

```
Execute("KeywordTests.LoginToTEST.Variables.TestURL = Project.Variables.BaseURL+KeywordTests.LoginToTEST.Variables.PageURL")
```

To me this seems a messy way of doing it, but i haven't been able to find a cleaner way to get this setup. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a Name Mapping scheme with a tested page mapping object that use a project variable as the value of the URL property. In this case, you can create your test specifying the simple mapping name for the page without any runtime calculations. For example:

Assume, you have mapped two pages on the same host server using project variables:
[image]

Variables for both pages and the host are specified in the following way:
[image]

In this case, you can work with pages by naming them with usual names:

```
function test()
{
  var google = Aliases.browser.pageGoogle;
  var gmail = Aliases.browser.pageGMail;

  if (google.Exists)
    Log.Message("The Google page is opened: " + Project.Variables.varGooglePage);

  if (gmail.Exists)
    Log.Message("The GMail page is opened: " + Project.Variables.varGMailPage);
}
```

To avoid modifying the values of all the variables when the host is changed, you can change the value only of the **testedHost** variable and make use of the [OnStartTest event](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/70540/) handler to update values of other variables correspondingly:

```
function GeneralEvents_OnStartTest(Sender)
{
  Project.Variables.varGooglePage = "https://www." + Project.Variables.testedHost + "*";
  Project.Variables.varGMailPage = "https://mail." + Project.Variables.testedHost + "/mail/u/0/*";
}
```

You can read the value of the **testedHost** variable in this handler from the TestComplete command line, from external file, request it from the tester using a [user form](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/69674/) and so on.